# Why the property dbo: leader has out of date values in DBpedia-live?

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I want to query DBpedia with DBpedia Live endpoint for the resource `United States` (e.g., (dbr:Barack_Obama dbr:John_Roberts dbr:Joe_Biden dbr:Paul_Ryan ) ) using dbo: leader. However, I get out of date values from DBpedia live.

Comment: and you tried what? where is your query or what you tried so far? It would also be good to use the text in the question title is the content itself.

Comment: and to answer your question, it has multiple leader values because the data comes from Wikipedia via infobox mappings. And clearly, the semantics of `dbo:leader` is also a bit vague. You can see this from the values of the property `dbo:leaderTitle` with the values `dbo:leaderTitle  

    Chief Justice (en)
    President (en)
    Vice President (en)
    Speaker of the House (en)
` - so basically each of those outdated person had probably on of those roles as leader. And yes, data quality of DBpedia is far from being perfect

Comment: by the way, there is no such property at all for USA right now which looks a bit weird. Not sure what's going on there, most of the data is not available for `dbr:Unoted_States` - that must be some technical issue or bug

Comment: My question is essentially about the outdated data, since DBpedia-Live was made to overcome the lack of synchronization between DBpedia and wikipedia and to enhance data freshness, but I noticed that the data in DBpedia-Live are also obsolete than DBpedia

Comment: The leaders you name are on the [DBpedia page for United States](http://dbpedia.org/page/United_States), not on the [DBpedia-Live page for United States](http://live.dbpedia.org/page/United_States). I think you've got an error somewhere else. (Also, there are no `dbo:leader` values on the current DBpedia-Live page, which may be for many reasons, including intentional changes in DBpedia extractors, bugs in the same, recent edits to the Wikipedia page, and others.)

Comment: In future, it will speed things up if you provide the URIs of the endpoints you're looking at, and not just the literal names.

Answer (score 0):

DBpedia Live processing had stalled, and this stall had gone un-noticed for some time.  The stall has since been resolved, and the OP's concern prompting this question seems likely to also have been resolved.